# confirm message using codebehind c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I was assigned to do a task...Confirmation message for password change.i want to do this from code behind file of Asp.net.when i click save button,display a msg for confirmation,after all serverside validation.when i click ok,then the password changes successfully,and save values to database.when i click cancel,return false.
here i write a cde for this,

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
  "OpenConfirm", "if(confirm('Confirm Password Change?'));", true);
```

But using this code,confirmation msg display on button click after all validation,but the checking is not working properly.that means the confirmation msg display and the user selection have no effect.user click ok/cancel,we got a msg password change successfully.Its wrong,i want that msg only on clicking ok.

Comment: are you facing any probs to do it on client side? any special purpose to this on server side?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenConfirm", "confirm('Confirm Password Change?')", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

show this confirm message on button OnclientClickEvent
Something like this

```
<asp:Button ID = "btn" runat = "server" OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete');" />
```